# Using weblogic Authorization without authentication

Tags: authorization, weblogic

I have implemented OAM SSO Authentication for my web application deployed on weblogic. Now i want use weblogic embedded LDAP to provide app level authorization. I dont want to use the weblogic authentication, just the authorization since i already have authentication handled by OAM. Is that possible? Can someone please point me to any examples, tutorials, or ideas to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OAM version, you need to add a OAMIdentityAsserter Provider in your WLS domain.  I say depending on your OAM verison, because you need to tell it which type of cookies to use.

OAM Admin guide will tell you how to do this.